# PDFMake Base64 generates malformed document

Tags: javascript, base64, data-uri, pdfmake

I'm using PDFMake to generate some PDF reports on client side.
When I specify the definition for document and pass it to `createPdf(DEFINITION_HERE)` I get my PDF and it looks nice and shiny. But I'm saving it in the DB as Base64 encoded string and when I try to reopen it with data URI (ie: `data:application/pdf;base64,JVBER...`) the document is completely malformed.

My DB call looks like this:

```
await pdfFile.getDataUrl(async (result: string) => {
      await myServiceLayer.generatePdfReport(result, fileName, creator);
});
```

Anyone else had this issue with PDFMake library? Any ideas on what could be the cause of this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so after trying different things and debugging left and right, I stumbled upon this:

https://github.com/bpampuch/pdfmake/issues/318

So I removed call to `.download()` on my PDF file and checked for Base64 again, now it had correct value and file looks as it should.

So in a nutshell, if we call multiple methods on PDFMake, usually something will get messed up.

I had my `.download()` call just before my `.getBase64()` as I wanted to first download the file for the user and then also store it in DB as Base64, as `.download()` happened `.getBase64()` kept on giving me Base64 output which resulted in malformed PDF file.